# Mysql where clause for million rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, t1,t2 in schema - 'Schema,
t1 has 1 million rows and around 30 columns.

I am running a query like one given below,

```
select b.Contract_ID,
b.Signed, 
b.Funding_Source,
b.Theater, b.Country,
b.Partner, b.BEID, 
b.Contract_Type, b.TCV,
b.Technology, 
b.Partner_Signature_Date,
b.Signature_Date, b.Term,
b.Purchase_Order, 
b.Contract_Baseline,
b.Organic_Rate, b.Target_Organic, 
b.Target_Incremental,
b.Total_Bookings_Target,
b.Tracking_Start, 
b.Tracking_End, b.Qualifier_BEID, 
b.Qualifier_BEGeoID, 
a.`CSC Global Ultimate ID`, 
a.`CSC Company Target ID`,
b.Qualifier_Theater, 
b.Qualifier_Country, a.SCMS,
b.Qualifier_POType, b.MCO, 
b.Contract_Status, b.Accrual_Start, 
b.Accrual_End, b.Booking_Start, 
b.Booking_End, b.TMS_Level_1, 
b.TMS_Level_2, b.TMS_Level_3, 
b.Pf, 
b.Allocation,a.`Fiscal Period ID`,
a.Bookings*b.Allocation as Bookings  
from
(SELECT * FROM `Schema`.`t1` where `BEID` in 
(select distinct (BEID) from Schema.`t2`)) a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM `Schema`.`t2`) b
where
a.`Business Entity Id` = b.Qualifier_BEID
and a.`BE Geo Id` = b.Qualifier_BEGeoID
and a.`Country` = b.Qualifier_Country
and a.`PO Type` = b.Qualifier_POType 
and a.`Product Family` = b.Pf
```

This is the query, but it is taking 45 minutes to run. A little background about a few things.

1. `select distinct (BEID) from Schema.`t2

results in 137 numeric values (all maximum 4 digits).

2. I have BIED column indexed, so alias 'a' would be a bit faster to calculate.

Comment: Will you stick around to reward the answer after you first show complete schema with indexes on related tables?

Comment: You are mixing implicit and explicit JOIN forms. Use `ON` for all join conditions and `WHERE` for post-join ones.

Comment: Why build temporary tables?

Answer (score 1):

First off, write the query like this

```
select b.Contract_ID,

b.Signed, 
b.Funding_Source,
b.Theater, b.Country,
b.Partner, b.BEID, 
b.Contract_Type, b.TCV,
b.Technology, 
b.Partner_Signature_Date,
b.Signature_Date, b.Term,
b.Purchase_Order, 
b.Contract_Baseline,
b.Organic_Rate, b.Target_Organic, 
b.Target_Incremental,
b.Total_Bookings_Target,
b.Tracking_Start, 
b.Tracking_End, b.Qualifier_BEID, 
b.Qualifier_BEGeoID, 
a.`CSC Global Ultimate ID`, 
a.`CSC Company Target ID`,
b.Qualifier_Theater, 
b.Qualifier_Country, a.SCMS,
b.Qualifier_POType, b.MCO, 
b.Contract_Status, b.Accrual_Start, 
b.Accrual_End, b.Booking_Start, 
b.Booking_End, b.TMS_Level_1, 
b.TMS_Level_2, b.TMS_Level_3, 
b.Pf, 
b.Allocation,a.`Fiscal Period ID`,
a.Bookings*b.Allocation as Bookings



from

`Schema`.`t1` a
INNER JOIN
`Schema`.`t2` b on a.BEID = b.BEID


where
a.`Business Entity Id` = b.Qualifier_BEID

and a.`BE Geo Id` = b.Qualifier_BEGeoID 

and a.`Country` = b.Qualifier_Country 

and a.`PO Type` = b.Qualifier_POType 

and a.`Product Family` = b.Pf
```

second, make sure you created an index on `Schema`.`t1`.BEID AS WELL AS schema.t2

Answer (score 1):

Make it a standard join without subqueries, and move all conditions up into the join condition. Use `distinct` only if a BEID can appear multiple times in t2.

```
select distinct
    -- various columns as per your posted query
from t1 a
join t2 b on a.BEID = b.BEID
    and a.`Business Entity Id` = b.Qualifier_BEID
    and a.`BE Geo Id` = b.Qualifier_BEGeoID
    and a.`Country` = b.Qualifier_Country
    and a.`PO Type` = b.Qualifier_POType 
    and a.`Product Family` = b.Pf
```

Put an index on `t2(BEID)`, or better on `t2(BEID, Qualifier_BEID, Qualifier_BEGeoID)`

I omitted the columns because they are not important to the problem.